# How to write unit test methods for aspx.cs files in VS 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to write unit test methods for VS 2008?
- On Submission of User Name and Password, i have called the method which is .aspx.cs file.I need to write the unit test for the methods which are defined in .aspx.cs file.
-From .aspx.cs file, i have called the methods which is in separate file.
- So i need to cover the code which is in .aspx.cs file and also in .cs file.
So my question is, can we write test methods .aspx.cs file?

Answer (score 2):

I would take the code which you want to test, and move it to a seperate class. It sounds like this method belongs in a class which is responsible for validating users. Then your aspx.cs file can use this class to validate users.

If you really want to do it, then this might help you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/5c984f7f-31c9-48ef-b8e5-c9c8357431ae